# I cannot understand how the "if" and "or" are working here

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

```
if player[2] != (0 or 4 or 7 or 10 or 30):
    print("hi")
else:
    print("bye")
```

In my program, `player[2]` is clearly `7`. However, when I run this, it returns `"hi"` instead of `"bye"`. Why? And how would I go about testing that `player[2]` is not any of these numbers without writing a separate `if` statement for each?

Comment: The parenthesis is evaluated first, and that result is compared to `player[2]` - it's not comparing with each of the element, it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: Hint: `(0 or 4 or 7 or 10 or 30) is 4`

Comment: So how would I go about fixing it? I know that I could write a separate if statement for each but that seems quite inefficient

Comment: @ohjuny: `if player[2] not in (0, 4, 7, 10, 30):`

Comment: It is absolutely a duplicate, just put things the other way around.